# Referencing Parent Div within Ajax Succes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I want to hide a parent div when a link is clicked and an ajax call is made successfully. If I place the hide() within the success part of the ajax it doesn't work:

```
$('.mylink').click(function(){

     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: dataString,
          url: "includes/edit-packages.php",
          success:function(){

               $(this).parent().slideUp('slow');

          }


     });

return false;

});
```

Although this works outside of the success:

```
$('.mylink').click(function(){

         $(this).parent().slideUp('slow');

});
```

How can I reference `$(this).parent()` within the success part of the ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/fAjLM8hS9BmdQ7tJ0UZA?p=preview

Basically `this` isn't referring to the same HTML element anymore, it's actually referring to the window object within the success function (A simple [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) of the variable `this` helps a lot!).

To get the functionality you want, define a new variable just outside the ajax call:

```js
$('.myLink').click(function() {
    var myLink = $(this);
    // wait 2 seconds to simulate an Ajax call somewhat
    setTimeout(function() {
      myLink.parent().slideUp('slow');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have several elements of the same class, when I try your method it hides all of these. I only want to hide the element which from where the click came from, hence the use of this.

Comment: I've updated the Plunker example and my answer. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Wow thank you Trevor, so simple and does the job perfectly. Final question, imagine the "click me" text is dynamically generated html and reads "click me1", "click me2", "clickme3" and so on.... if the link is clicked it slides up and the link text is updated. So if "click me2" is clicked, "clickme3" becomes "clickme2". Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: It is possible, but I'd suggest that you make a new question specific to that issue and link back to this question as a reference. That's a completely different question! Make sure to use the `javascript` and `jquery` tags along with whatever backend you're using (`php` / etc) to render the page to get more views & help. Makes sure to [mark this answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187921) if you feel it answers the question. Good luck!